# Upgrade Infragistics dlls from vesrion 11.1 to 18.1

Tags: infragistics

We are using the follow Infragistics dlls in project.

Infragistics35.Web.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.Documents.Core.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.Documents.Excel.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.Documents.Reports.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.Misc.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.Shared.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.DocumentExport.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ExcelExport.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebListbar.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.WebCombo.v11.1

Infragistics35.WebUI.WebDateChooser.v11.1

Can i upgrade to the latest version 18.1 without changing code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the Version Upgrade Utility. Read the following article: https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/web-using-version-upgrade-utility

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated my entire solution (80+ projects) from IG 12.2 to 16.2.  As Jackdaw mentioned there is a version upgrade utility.  Within VS I was able to right-click on each project and run the upgrade from there.  I had no issues whatsoever.  Unfortunately IG 16.2 is the most recent version approved by my security folks, but I can't imagine going from 11.1 to 18.1 would be any different.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do so, without any code changes, because those controls were retired in the very next version Infragistics ASP.NET 2011 vol2.

[Changes after version ASP.NET 2011 vol.2](https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/known-issues-known-issues-and-breaking-changes-revision-history)

There are several sources you could use to make the upgrade easier for you:

[Product Changes fully described for 2011 vol.2](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/taz_abdeali/posts/asp-net-product-changes-in-2011-volume-2)

[New controls starting from ASP.NET 2011 Vol.2](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/taz_abdeali/posts/asp-net-product-changes)

And a helpful document describing some of the changes that you could easily perform when migrating from the old control to a new one in the following [cheat sheet](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/craig_shoemaker/posts/introducing-the-webdatagrid-webhierarchicaldatagrid-cheat-sheet).